# Using PHP To Get Folder Images Shows Extra Blank Space

Tags: php, html, gallery, directory

I'm using php to get & display the images in a folder and everything has been working fine until I added the NEW images to the folder - It's now adding a blank space before the first gallery image. When I echo out the `$count` it shows that there are 8 files instead of the 7 that there actually are. What is the reason for this and how can I prevent it?

My PHP code is:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <h1>Take A Look Around:</h1>
    <p>
        <?php

        $folder = 'gallery/';
        $filetype = '*.*';
        $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
        $count = count($files);
        for ($i = ($count-1); $i >= 0; $i--) {
            echo '<div class="photoHolder"><div class="photoCell"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$files[$i].'"><img class="photo" src="'.$files[$i].'" alt=""></a></div></div>';
        }
        ?>
    <div class="clearLeft"></div><?php echo $count; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
<div id="gallery">
    <h1>Take A Look Around:</h1>
    <p><?php

        $folder = 'gallery/';
        $filetype = '*.*';
        $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            echo '<div class="photoHolder"><div class="photoCell"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'"><img class="photo" src="'.$file.'" alt=""></a></div></div>';
        }
        ?></p>
    <div class="clearLeft"></div>
    <p><?php echo count($files); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, This gives me exactly the same ouput except the space is after the gallery image

Comment: Even though this doesn't quite solve my problem I'm giving it a + vote because with the space being now at the end of the gallery it isn't noticable - Thanks

Comment: I just modified the code slightly (moved the `</p>` back) - does that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check in the for loop if the item `$files[$i]` is really a file. Often when you loop in a directory you also have the values `.` and/or `..`. Your filetype doesnt filter that out.

```
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if(is_file($folder.$files[$i])
        {
            echo '<div class="photoHolder"><div class="photoCell"><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'.$file.'"><img class="photo" src="'.$file.'" alt=""></a></div></div>';
        }
    }
```